# Adding new ROWID to SQLite SELECT statement based on the UNION of several tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, integer, rowid

Consider the following `SQLite` statement where each `product_id` may appear at least once in each table. The purpose of our `SELECT` statement being to merge all the `product_id`'s into one table.

```
SELECT product_id
  FROM product_id_table_UK
UNION
SELECT product_id
  FROM product_id_table_DE
UNION
SELECT product_id
  FROM product_id_table_ES
UNION
SELECT product_id
  FROM product_id_table_IT
UNION
SELECT product_id
  FROM product_id_table_FR
```

How can one add an `ID INTEGER` column to the resulting view?

Each table has it's own `ID INTEGER` column but if we `SELECT ID` column then we will have duplicate `product_id` columns in the new view with separate `ID`'s.

Addding `ROWID` doesn't work since it returns the `ID`s of the tables.

Furthermore views do not have rows stored in them.

Comment: If you're using 3.25 you can use the `row_number()` window function on the results of that union, but that's just cosmetic. Maybe a temp table? What are you going to use this id column for?

Comment: Fix your data structure so you have all the products in one table to begin with, with an identifier for the customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is painful in older versions of SQLite (pre-`row_number()` days).  You can do:

```
with p as (
      SELECT product_id
      FROM product_id_table_UK
      UNION
      SELECT product_id
      FROM product_id_table_DE
      UNION
      SELECT product_id
      FROM product_id_table_ES
      UNION
      SELECT product_id
      FROM product_id_table_IT
      UNION
      SELECT product_id
      FROM product_id_table_FR
     )
select p.*,
       (select count(*) from p p2 where p2.product_id <= p.product_id)
from p;
```